# ng-repeat does not work when array (or string) has non-unique values

Tags: angularjs

I have this line of code in my AngularJS template:

```
        <span ng-repeat="letter in word">{{letter}}&nbsp;</span>
```

'word' is a string. 
It works fine unless word contains the same letter twice. For example for the word 'boy' it works fine and renders the string "b o y ", but for the words 'ball' or 'elephant' nothing is rendered. The same problem occurs when iterating over an array of one letter strings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Change your repeater to use this:

```
<span ng-repeat="letter in word track by $index">{{letter}}&nbsp;</span>
```

Docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes

Comment: Thank you for the fast and accurate answer!

Comment: I ran into the same problem myself over the weekend, so it was fresh on my mind.

Comment: would love to know why this doesn't work on its own; but glad one of the top hits on google was a work around that did work.

Comment: @Mike_Matthews_II I think ng is unable to add its own tracking id since the collection is a simple object (string).