# Angular list not updating on watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I have been using some angular controllers for get/post requests a few times and thus not too experienced with angular (or JS in any way, I'm the backend type not frontend), but got a problem I have been trying to solve past week for a private project, without success. I tried any solution I could find here. Hopefully someone can help.

I get 1x JSON object from backend containing 4x strings, and a list of strings.

```
{
  'var1':'abc',
  'var2':'def',
  'var3':'ghi',
  'var4':'jkl',
  'images':['images/abcd.jpg', 'images/efgh.jpg']
}
```

The gui updates all 4 strings but not the list.

Controller:

```
app.controller('ObjectInfoController', function ($scope, $window, $http) {

        $scope.$watch('images', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            alert(newValue);
        });

        $http.post("http://localhost:8080/view_object/", postdata).then(
            function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.var1 = data.data.var1;
            $scope.var2 = data.data.var2;
            $scope.var3 = data.data.var3;
            $scope.var4 = data.data.var4;
            $scope.images = data.data.images;
            $scope.$digest();
        },
        function(err) {
            // Do something
        }
    );
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="ObjectInfoController">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- Images -->
        <div class="owl-carousel content-slider-with-controls-autoplay">
            <div class="overlay-container overlay-visible" ng-repeat="image in images">
                <img src="{{image}}" alt="">
                <div class="overlay-bottom hidden-xs">

                </div>
                <a href="{{image}}" class="popup-img overlay-link"><i class="icon-plus-1"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Images end -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 pv-30 TextBlock bottomFix">
        <h2 class="TextBlockTitle">{{var1}}</h2>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="icon-right-open-outline"><strong>{{var2}}</strong></li>
            <li class="icon-right-open-outline"><strong>{{var3}}</strong></li>
            <li class="icon-right-open-outline"><strong>{{var4}}</strong></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I saw people using watches to fix this problem (although I do not get why the list needs it but not remaining data), but cannot get it to work.

See the alert() I do inside the watch? With that alert I get the images in my ng-repeat and all looks good. Removing the alert, and it doesn't work. Does an alert do some sort of "update" to the view, and can I force it without alerting?

I actually get 2 alerts popping up, first is empty and second prints my list, but that is normal I found out. I tried setting $scope.images inside watch too, with no luck.

I feel there is either something trivial I didn't understand, or I should not use watch but something else?
Please enlighten me if you know what I am doing wrong. I feel clueless by now.

And thanks for your time.

Edit: just did a random test and typed {{images[0]}} after {{var1}} and the correct value was written out on the page.... so the problem seems to only exist in my ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why you would need the $watch. You also shouldn't call $digest unless you have a specific reason to do so.

It's a good idea to use the [controllerAs-syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) as it makes the scope exlicit. Change your controller declaration in the html to `<div class="row" ng-controller="ObjectInfoController as vm">`, and refer to your variables through `vm` in the template, e.g. `ng-repeat="image in vm.images"`.

```
app.controller('ObjectInfoController', function ($http) {
    var vm = this;

    $http.post("http://localhost:8080/view_object/", postdata).then(
        function(data, status, headers, config) {
            vm.var1 = data.data.var1;
            vm.var2 = data.data.var2;
            vm.var3 = data.data.var3;
            vm.var4 = data.data.var4;
            vm.images = data.data.images;
        },
        function(err) {
            // Do something
        }
    );
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8aLgfr48/6/)

Also, [you should use `ng-src` instead of `src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) when you use variables in the img-element source.

If it still doesn't work, I suspect the problem has something to do with owl-carousel - try to loop over the images variables outside the owl-carousel.

Comment: Thank you. Replaced with ng-src and removed digest. Thought digest was needed to "trigger" watch as I saw it used in other watch examples. However it did not work to just assign $scope.images like in your example. That was my original code which didnt work and lead me to try and find a solution. I tried it again just to make sure but it didnt work. Still only shows if watching and alerting :(

Comment: Also it doesn't seem to be a problem reading the list outside of the ng-repeat. Just updated the post.

Comment: Did you try ng-src? Or are the divs not being created?

Comment: I tried that. And no, the divs are not being created. Like if it looks in the "wrong" scope for my list, only for that repeat as right under the repeat I can manually get to the items by using indexing on the list.

Comment: @Kleggas: I updated the answer with new things to try.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible two values in the images array are equal, change your ng-repeat expression to

```
ng-repeat="image in images track by $index"
```

ng-repeat with primitives requires some care.  I'd have just suggested this in a comment but I don't have the rep.

See [this](http://www.codelord.net/2014/05/10/understanding-angulars-magic-dont-bind-to-primitives/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22821948/ng-repeat-does-not-work-when-array-or-string-has-non-unique-values)

Comment: I had no idea. Thanks for the info. It didn't make the images show up, but I learned something good that I had no idea about.

Comment: Using 'track by' you might try changing your {{image}} expressions to {{images[$index]}}

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are  using primitive datatype and not object which provide two-way data binding.

> Primitive datatype is not provide two-way data binding.

`vm.var1, vm.var2` etc are primitive datatype.

You should changes the script and html as follows.

JS:

```
$http.post("http://localhost:8080/view_object/", postdata).then(
            function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.objData = data.data;
        },
        function(err) {
            // Do something
        }
```

HTML :

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="icon-right-open-outline"><strong>{{objData.var2}}</strong></li>
    <li class="icon-right-open-outline"><strong>{{objData.var3}}</strong></li>
    <li class="icon-right-open-outline"><strong>{{objData.var4}}</strong></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I see. Storing away the complete object and taking the parts I need when needed. I will try this later today when I get time. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this has to do with two-way binding, here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8aLgfr48/6/

Comment: What your example is proving?

Comment: Using $scope instead: https://jsfiddle.net/fajuwn09/2/ . You can see that the problem isn't the one you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all answers worked. Even my original code worked (which was a modified copy/paste from another page I used ng-repeat on. I found out by performing same ng-repeat code in a new div before the one that didn't work, just printing the {{image}} and had no problems.

Problem I took for granted past few days were located in my controller, was actually a css problem...

Im sorry for wasting time, but thankful to learn a bit more about what the different code you posted is for :)